# Questions about whether multi-threaded operation of QMap is safe

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt5.15.2, Now I have a main thread and a child thread, the child thread only modifies the QMap, and the main thread only reads the QMap. Neither the main thread nor the child threads are locked. Is this operation safe? Will it cause the program to crash?

This is the run function of the sub-thread:

```
QMap<QString, QMap<QString, bool>> g_map;
void subThread::run()
{
    while (!m_stop)
    {
        g_map[QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString()].insert(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(), flag);
        flag = !flag;
    }
}
```

This is the function of the main thread:

```
void MainThread::run()
{
    for (auto key : g_map.keys())
    {
        qDebug() << key << " " << g_map.value(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if I don't see it explicitly mentioned in the documentation then I consider all operations thread-unsafe.

Comment: Qt collections are _not_ thread-safe.  You must provide your own locking if you are modifying in a different thread.  Alternatively, connect slots to ensure that only one thread accesses the collection.

Comment: If I want to write a single-threaded application, I do not want any additional, unnecessary overhead that would be introduced in a class.   This follows the [zero-overhead principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/Zero-overhead_principle) for C++ in general.  Thus QMap and basically any other collection class, be it from Qt, standard C++, or what have you, do *not* add thread-safety.  If you want thread-safety, you have to "opt-in" and write your own code.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this operation safe?

No. There is nothing in `QMap` that does the necessary synchronization for you so you need to add that yourself.

> Will it cause the program to crash?

Since the program has a race condition, the program has undefined behavior. It *could* crash - or it could run for years without any noticable problems - and then crash or produce erroneous results.

Answer (score 0):

The situation, I think, is more complicated than what the comments and the other answer say.

First: AFAICT, **your code is NOT safe** since both threads work on the same instance of the `QMap` (a global, not `thread_local` variable).
All the text below is the explanation as to why this is important.

There are 4 pages of documentation that specify how Qt container classes work:

- The [Container classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/containers.html) page; Quotes:

  > The container classes are implicitly shared, they are reentrant, and they are optimized for speed, low memory consumption, and minimal inline code expansion, resulting in smaller executables. In addition, they are thread-safe in situations where they are used as read-only containers by all threads used to access them.

  > Implicit sharing has another consequence on STL-style iterators: you should avoid copying a container while iterators are active on that container. The iterators point to an internal structure, and if you copy a container you should be very careful with your iterators.
- The [Reentrancy and thread-safety](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-reentrancy.html) page; Quote:

  > By extension, a class is said to be reentrant if its member functions can be called safely from multiple threads, as long as each thread uses a different instance of the class
- The [Thread-support in Qt modules](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-modules.html) page; Quotes:

  > Qt uses an optimization called implicit sharing for many of its value class, notably QImage and QString. Beginning with Qt 4, implicit shared classes can safely be copied across threads, like any other value classes. They are fully reentrant. The implicit sharing is really implicit.

  > Note that atomic reference counting does not guarantee thread-safety. Proper locking should be used when sharing an instance of an implicitly shared class between threads. This is the same requirement placed on all reentrant classes, shared or not. Atomic reference counting does, however, guarantee that a thread working on its own, local instance of an implicitly shared class is safe. We recommend using signals and slots to pass data between threads, as this can be done without the need for any explicit locking.
- The page treating [implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/implicit-sharing.html); Quotes:

  > Qt's container iterators have different behavior than those from the STL.

  > When dealing with shared objects, there are two ways of copying an object. We usually speak about deep and shallow copies. A deep copy implies duplicating an object. A shallow copy is a reference copy, i.e. just a pointer to a shared data block. Making a deep copy can be expensive in terms of memory and CPU. Making a shallow copy is very fast, because it only involves setting a pointer and incrementing the reference count.

  > Object assignment (with operator=()) for implicitly shared objects is implemented using shallow copies.

  > Implicit sharing automatically detaches the object from a shared block if the object is about to change and the reference count is greater than one. (This is often called copy-on-write or value semantics.)

I strongly advice you to read all 4 pages. There is no right or wrong order for that; most likely, you will have to come back to pages you have already opened to read them again with the context from the page you are currently reading.

Of course, the documentation of [QMap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmap.html) mentions:

> Note: All functions in this class are reentrant.

That is a lot of information at once... What all of that means is:

1. If your threads only read from the container, it is safe.
2. If a thread writes into a container, it must do so on a local copy of it.
   Before writing, the data is **implicitly shared** between the containers living in their respective thread.
   After writing, the containers are **detached**, they do not share data anymore.
   Like mentioned in the documentation, the iterators for Qt containers behave differently than iterators from the STL, so while writing in a different thread is allowed, **it will invalidate all your iterators**, including iterators that the STL would leave intact (there is an example in the [implicit sharing iterator problem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/containers.html#implicit-sharing-iterator-problem)).

Because of all of the above, the below code where all writing operations are done on local copies of the `QMap`, before any iterator is created is safe.
Note that **the main thread will not see what the worker thread has written** because the instances are detached right before it is effective.

Note: I have introduced waiting times to make things slow enough for the human eye.

```cpp
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
public:
    WorkerThread(QMap<int, int> v) : values(v) {}
    void run() override {
        values.insert(11, 12); values.insert(13, 14); values.insert(15, 16); values.insert(17, 18); values.insert(19, 20); values.insert(21, 22);
        for (auto v = values.begin(); v != values.end(); ++v)
        {
            QThread::msleep(800);
            std::cout << "From thread: " << v.key() << ", " << v.value() << '\n';
        }

    }
private:
    QMap<int, int> values;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMap<int, int> values;
    values.insert(1, 2); values.insert(3, 4); values.insert(5, 6); values.insert(7, 8); values.insert(9, 10);

    WorkerThread* workerThread = new WorkerThread(values);
    QObject::connect(workerThread, &QThread::finished, workerThread, &QThread::deleteLater);

    workerThread->start();
    for (auto v = values.begin(); v != values.end(); ++v)
    {
        QThread::msleep(2000);
        std::cout << "From Main: " << v.key() << ", " << v.value() << '\n';
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Final note: despite my initial disagreement with the comments, I will say they are mostly right though:

- If the thread-safety is not explicitly mentioned, then it is not thread-safe.
- If you want to work with a single instance of a container (rather than 2 instances like my code above), then you must indeed implement a locking mechanism.
  This looks very complicated though, as iterators are invalidated in different ways than the STL. I am unsure it is at all possible because of this.

Comment: And what is new in your comment from the others? Apart form this `I am unsure it is at all possible because of this.` is simply wrong.

Comment: I'm looking at the Qt5 source for `QMap`. `T value(const Key &key, const T &defaultValue = T()) const { if (!d) return defaultValue; const auto i = d->m.find(key); if (i != d->m.cend()) return i->second; return defaultValue; }` where `d` is a `QtPrivate::QExplicitlySharedDataPointerV2<std::map<Key, T>>`. Its `operator bool()` does nothing to synchronize. It simply returns the internal `std::map<Key, T>*`. The `m.find` operation is done on a plain `std::map<Key, T>` so that's not safe either.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, you seem to only mention methods that read from the map, right? Then it is explicitly mentioned in the quotes I extracted that "[Containers] *are thread-safe in situations where they are used as read-only containers by all threads used to access them.*" If it is only reading, there is nothing to synchronize, right? Regarding getting an iterator to replace its pointed value inside the container, this is covered by the section called "Implicit sharing iterator problem" that I linked (it is prohibited).

Comment: Regarding the other ways to write into a container, I have not read the source code but the documentation suggests it is these methods that cause the container to be detached so it is the code for these methods that you have to look at. Or perhaps I have missed the point of your comment?

Comment: Anyway, what I wanted to explain in my answer is: 1. where to find the relevant documentation and 2. that the critical point in the code from OP is that threads work on the same instance of the container. If OP one day sees code he did not write himself of a container being used in several thread, he will have some keys to tell if it is one of the valid uses (although maybe not the behavior he expects) or, like the code in the question, UB.

Comment: When looking at the `git log` for these two classes, I couldn't find the word "thread" in more than one commit: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/8c9875893bbd7b1355e36d9501d8cb1f84cb6b4d - and it _does_ talk about the `detach`ing thing. If it actually does proper synchronization somehow, I can't see it.

Comment: @Atmo _"you seem to only mention methods that read from the map, right?"_ - Yes. It doesn't matter if you make the writing thread safe if reading from it doesn't synchronize with those writes. The `detach` function itself calls `d.detach()` (and `d` is a `QtPrivate::QExplicitlySharedDataPointerV2<QMapData<std::map<Key, T>>>`, not what I wrote above). This `detatch` method doesn't do synchronization that I can see but has this rather interesting comment: `// TODO: qAtomicDetach here...?`

Comment: It does not synchronize. After being detached, each map lives its own life. Synchronization is possible with signals/slots I suppose. But I see where you are coming from; I had initially written that *the main thread will not see what the worker thread has written* and this was mistakenly removed (by me) probably when I finally found the last page of documentation I was looking for. This lack of sync is what I meant when I said in my previous comment: "maybe not the behavior he expects". I see now that it must have been confusing for you; the missing sentence is now restored. Apologies.

Comment: _"It does not synchronize. After being detached..."_ - The way I read the code, the copy + `detach()` doesn't seem thread safe in itself.  I just made a small example with one writer thread and one reader thread and ran it with `ThreadSanitizer`. Got this: _WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race_.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/nE4z7r5T7

Comment: It is a bit late where I live so I'm not going to dive deep in the code right now but the logic seems to be: 1. Create the copy of the container (let's say there are only 2 instances of the QMap here, so the reference counter is `2`). 2. fork a new thread

Comment: 3. When either thread modifies data, it checks the value of its `ref` atomic int. If it sees more than 1, it copies the content. Interestingly, the constructor used for this does not call `ref->ref();` to increase the counter but the destructor does call calling `ref->deref();`, so the counter is decremented when the copy goes out of scope (a `swap` takes place just before that, so the object that goes out of scope does not bring the data down with it).

Comment: If I follow the logic correctly, if the 2nd thread also modifies the content while the first is still in the middle of detaching itself, if will also make a copy for its own use before the counter is decremented. At this point, it reaches 0 so the memory is cleared making the copy made by the 2nd thread "unnecessary" (by that I mean: the 2nd thread had to make the copy because it could not know the first thread was in the middle of detaching its map but the timing was unfortunate, and the original data has to be deleted at the end of the operation).

Comment: At the end of the day, the code you posted on gobolt is the one from the question, which indeed is unsafe (since there is only 1 instance). With the way the whole thing is coded (without a mutex), I'm not completely sure how the thread sanitizer can figure out everything is in fact fine when done correctly. And this `// TODO: qAtomicDetach here...?` that I have seen too is rather concerning (although it falls just short of being a deal-breaker)...

Comment: My conclusion (as of tonight): it is indeed not thread-safe per se (except the `QAtomicInt` counter), and the thing that makes it visible is that it seems maps may make 1 too many copy of the data in case of a bad timing. With that said, it appears writing in 2 instances of a Qt container simultaneously in 2 threads will successfully detach them from one another.